# Widget design in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

In the past week I am trying to learn Angular JS. I mostly used jQuery on my projects so I am having hard time trying to get its concept. I decided to make a simple admin panel using angularjs for myself to use it on my projects. With this, I can learn angular while trying to to things. But I couldn't find a correct way to do it Since its completely new concept then jQuery.

Here is what I try to do:
I have a header bar on my page. In this header page there is some links (with dropdowns) like notification panel, user profile links, search panel. I called each of them widgets.

Here is my header bar html code:

```
<header class="bg-dark dk header navbar navbar-fixed-top-xs">
  <div class="navbar-header aside-md">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/logo.png" class="m-r-sm">Notebook</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-xs">
    <li dropdown>
      <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>Activities</a>
      <section class="dropdown-menu">
        <p>Some activities</p>
      </section>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right m-n hidden-xs nav-user">
    <li class="hidden-xs" dropdown>
      <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-sm up bg-danger m-l-n-sm count">2</span>
      </a>
      <section class="dropdown-menu aside-xl">
        <p>some notifications</p>
      </section>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

As you can see. there is two `ul.navbar-nav` one is left widget area, other is right widget area. What I want to accomplish is make these areas modular.
when I create a new directive for header-bar, I want it to automaticly update the header-nav. I mean each `<li/>` will be a directive and will have its on purposes. (eg. activity widget, notifications widget, user widget, search widget etc.)

What I think about this patern:

- A controller that holds in its scope the widget lists
- 2 Directives for left widget area and right widget area that watches changes on the controller scope's widget list and adds to its area.
- A service for widget directives that helps them to add themselves to controller scope's widget list.
- I thinked that there should be a priority option that lets widgets to order accordingly.

I don't know if this design pattern is right. Also I am not exactly know how to do them. Could you please tell me if this pattern is right. Also could you write a mini angular code that accomplish what I trying to do. I am sure alot of people will use that code when they try to learn AngularJS.

Comment: [ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) and examples using are a good start. Think of it in terms of a wrapping `<div>` where the attribute is assigned. Any "children" of that element belong to that controller, unless otherwise assigned to another controller. That is the general concept of seperating controller code. To more consice I think there needs to be more detail on your "widget" actions and elements. But that is a good starting point.